# React: How can I call a method only once in the lifecycle of a component, as soon as data.loading is false

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component with a prop 'total' that changes every time the component is updated:

```
function MyView(props) {
  const total = props.data.loading ? 0 : props.data.total;
  return (
    <p> total </p>
  );
}
```

The first time the component mounts the total is say 10. Every time the component is updated because of a prop change the total goes up.

Is there a way I can display the original total (in this example 10)?

I have tried setting it in this.total inside componentDidMount, but props.data.total is not yet available when componentDidMount is called. Same with the constructor. The total only becomes available when props.data.loading is false.

Comment: You can render 0 if data loading or props.data.total if not

Answer (score 3):

You could create a stateful component and store the initial `total` in the component state.

**Example**

```
class MyView extends React.Component {
  state = {
    initialTotal: this.props.total
  };
  render() {
    const { total } = this.props;
    const { initialTotal } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <p> Total: {total} </p>
        <p> Initial total: {initialTotal} </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    total: 10
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(({ total }) => {
        return { total: total + 1 };
      });
    }, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {
    return <MyView total={this.state.total} />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to get access to lifecycle features, you must move from function, stateless component, [to a class component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components).

in the below example, `InitialTotal` is initialized in the `construstor` lifecycle method and it never changes.

`currentTotal`, is incremented each time the render function is called - when the component is re-rendered (because of props change or state changes)

it should look something like that:

```
class MyView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.initialTotal = 10;
    this.currentTotal = 10;
  }
  render() {
    this.currentTotal+=1;
    return (
      <p>InitialToal: {this.initialTotal}</p>
      <p>Current Total: {this.currentTotal}</p>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Nowadays, you don't need to switch to a class component. You can use [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirements correctly...

```
function MyView(props) {
      // if you only need to set the value once on load just use useState.
      // the const total will be the value you pass in to useState.
      const [total, setTotal] = useState(props.data.loading ? 0 : props.data.total)

      // if its possible that the value is not available on initial load and
      // you want to set it only once, when it becomes available, you can use 
      // useEffect with useState
      useEffect(() => {
        // some condition to know if data is ready to set
        if (!props.data.loading) {
          setTotal(props.data.total)
        }

      }, [props.data.total, setTotal, props.data.loading] 
      // this array allows you to limit useEffect to only be called when 
      // one of these values change. ( when total changes in this case, 
      // as the const function setTotal will not change 
      // ( but react will fuss if its used and not in the list ).

      return (
        <p> {total} </p>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same need. With a functional component, I need to store the inital snapshot of states, let user play with different state values and see their results immediately, eventually, they can just cancel and go back to the initial states. Apply the same structure to your problem, this is how it looks:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const TestView = (props: { data: any }) => {
    // setting default will help type issues if TS is used
    const [initialTotal, setInitialTotal] = useState(props.data.total)

    useEffect(() => {
        // some condition to know if data is ready to set
        setInitialTotal(props.data.total);
        // Critical: use empty array to ensure this useEffect is called only once.       
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
        <p> { initialTotal } </p>
        <p> { props.data.total } </p>
        </div>
    );
}

export default TestView
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`getDerivedStateFromProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) life cycle method.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state){

        if(props.data.total && (props.data.total==10)){
             return {
                 total : props.total // show total only when its 10
              }
         }else{
             return null; // does not update state
          }
    }
```